# c++: Partial template specialization, logical or compiler bug?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, specialization

I have a class `T` and a few template classes `D1, D2,...` which I mix and use as `D1<D2<...<Dn<T>>...>`. I would like to construct a template class which will take as argument a mixed class and do some stuff based on the parameters it has deducted. To make things simple assume only a single template class D.

```
template <class T, template <class> class D>
struct mix {
  using type = D<T>;
};

template <class X>
struct DoStuff;

// 1st version -- this does not compile...
template <class T, template <class> class D>
struct DoStuff< typename mix<T,D>::type > {
  using type = int;
};

// 2nd version -- this compiles
template <class T, template <class> class D>
struct DoStuff< D<T> > {
  using type = int;
};

int main() {
   return 0;
}
```

The 1st version of the specialization results in the following compilation error (GCC 4.8.3 on CygWin):

```
test.cpp:11:8: error: template parameters not used in partial specialization:
 struct DoStuff< typename mix<T,D>::type > {
        ^
test.cpp:11:8: error:         'T'
test.cpp:11:8: error:         'template<class> class D'
```

whereas the second compiles cleanly. I am puzzled here since the `mix<T,D>::type` used in the 1st version is exactly `D<T>` which is used in the 2nd version.

Is this a compiler bug or am I missing something? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: As a first approximation (int 99.9% of the cases), it's "never a compiler bug".

Comment: From `D<T>` in general case there may be an infinite `D`/`T` which is equal to `mix<T,D>::type`.

Comment: It is simply that a dependent nested name specifier is non-deducible.

Comment: this is a duplicate, but I can't find the other question